# Layout forces to use Expanded (RenderFlex children have non-zero flex error), but how to keep the layout from "expanding" as a result?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a layout for web app, which uses nested Columns (see code). And as it causes `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded` error, I am forced to wrap inner columns in Expanded widget. But this also has a side effect of expanding the inner column as much as possible, which I do not want. How do I stop the column from expanding unnecessarily?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 240,
            height: double.infinity,
            color: kSidemenuBgColor,
            child: const Sidemenu(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 25,
                vertical: 15,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurRadius: 8,
                            color: Colors.black12,
                          ),
                        ],
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 30,
                              vertical: 25,
                            ),
                            child:
                                TableTitleText(text: 'Sales Overview Report'),
                          ),
                          const Divider(
                            height: 1,
                            color: kBorderColor,
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 30,
                              vertical: 15,
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 140,
                                  height: 40,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 15,
                                    vertical: 10,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: kBorderColor,
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      BodyText(
                                        text: '1 day',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      ),
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.expand_more_outlined,
                                        color: kBorderColor,
                                        size: 22,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width: 460,
                                  height: 40,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 15,
                                    vertical: 10,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border.all(
                                      color: kBorderColor,
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: [
                                      BodyText(
                                        text:
                                            'Maharashtra / Buldhana / Khamgaon',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                      ),
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.expand_more_outlined,
                                        color: kBorderColor,
                                        size: 22,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(
                            height: 1,
                            color: kBorderColor,
                          ),
                          // DataTable2 widget goes here, but has no effect when commented out
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried removing either of the Expanded widgets, setting mainAxisSize of all Column widgets to MainAxisSize.min, but those actions break the layout and have no effect, respectively.

[image]